# In Jetbrain IDEs, How to show warnings on method parameter hover?

Tags: android, android-lint

In Android studio, If we write a log tag of more than 23 characters, it shows an underlined warning saying tag can't be more than 23 characters (pic for ref).

[image]

If we want to do something similar to our own method (maybe while writing a new library), How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want checks not covered by current release of lint, then you need to to write own rules. There's sample repo on github with sample custom rules: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I wanted. Thanks mate. And also, In this case, I cant actually distribute my custom link rules along with the library I package right? Any way I can make my lint rules reach the users of my library?

Comment: sure you can have your rules distributable as jar. You may need to search a bit on that but first randomly found tutorial on custom list rules seem to cover that too: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-custom-lint-checks-in-android/